# infinite population mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have got two models which are ( form, user )

each user has formId field which is the object id of the form object he has

each form has a field called userId which is for the user who has this form

the problem is that I am using mongoose-autopopulate package and if I changed the formId and userId fields to be auto-populated it will open an infinite population with no end

the problem is that some other schemas have a field called formId which is associated with the form object and in this case I want to populate the userId field to get the user info without populating again the formId field.

**Schemas Design**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  formId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Form',
    
    //this value used to auto populate for mongoose-autopopulate package
    autopopulate: true,
  },
})

//signing the mongoose-autopopulate plugin

...

//exporting the module




---------------



const formSchema = new Schema({
  address: String,
  bill: Number,
  //the id of the user who added this form
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    
    //this value used to auto populate for mongoose-autopopulate package
    autopopulate: true,
  },
})

//signing the mongoose-autopopulate plugin

...

//exporting the module




----------


const orderSchema = new Schema({
  products: [],
  deliveryBoy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Boy',
  },
  formId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Form',
    
    //this value used to auto populate for mongoose-autopopulate package
    autopopulate: true,
  },
})

//signing the mongoose-autopopulate plugin

...

//exporting the module
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use the maxDepth option [mongoose-autopopulate](https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/autopopulate#it-can-limit-the-depth-using-maxdepth)

for example

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
  products: [],
  deliveryBoy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Boy',
  },
  formId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Form',
    autopopulate: { maxDepth: 2 },
  },
})
```